# Any nice way to find number number of single digit ordered pairs $(a, b)$ such that $a!b! \gt a!+b!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, factorial

I have listed them all by brute force :

`a = 0,1 : no solutions
a = 2 : b = 3,4,5,...9
c = 3 : b = 2,3,4...9`

---

I'm wondering if there is a clever approach to this. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that 
$$a!b!\gt a!+b!\iff (a!-1)(b!-1)\gt 1$$
with $a!\ge 1,b!\ge 1$.

Comment: Ahh nice :) so a={0,1} or b={0,1} are not possible - this observation eliminates 20 permutations out of a total of 10^2 permutations ?

Comment: @user172209: No, it's not so simple. This observation eliminates 37 permutations. $a!-1=0,0,1,4,\cdots$ and $b!-1=0,0,1,4,\cdots$. If you draw the table, you see the answer.

Comment: @user172209: $(a!-1,b!-1)=(0,m),(n,0),(1,1)$ don't satisfy $(a!-1)(b!-1)\gt 1$. You need to count the number of these cases.

Comment: got it! thank you so much :)

Comment: @user172209: You are welcome. Glad to help you.